# Using cURL to get a URL that is returning JSON

Tags: php, curl

All,
I have the following code:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_many}");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
if ( ! empty( $contents ) ) {
    // Decode it.
            echo "it is in here";
    $tweet = json_decode( $contents );
}
```

This code never gets into the if statement because it isn't returning any results. Any idea on how to get this to return all of the results?

Thanks!

Comment: Works on my machine. Have you actually set the `$username` and `$how_many` variables? Make sure you enable error reporting at the top of your script, eg `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Phil Yes, oddly enough when I removed the https and made it http it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your server doesn't trust Twitter's certificate authority (you're probably getting an SSL error but not seeing it due to your error reporting settings).

Follow this guide to get it working - http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_many}");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($c);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    echo 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch);

curl_close($c);
```

Comment: When I dump the contents I get bool(false)